# Using Selenium WebDriver to retrieve value of a HTML div

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get a value from a div using this code:

```
input_field = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='display']")
input_field_value = input_field.text
```

HTML:

```
<div id="display" class="display xh-highlight">1</div>
```

But I failed.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: Can you please add any error codes and provide the full HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either:

```
input_field = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='display']")
input_field_value = input_field.text
```

or

```
input_field = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('display')
input_field_value = input_field.text
```

More can be read at this link: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.It should work.

```
input_field =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="display xh-highlight"]')
input_field_value = input_field.text
```